# Breeze JS Adding a static Lookup dictionary to Metadata

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

One of my domain models has an Enum property that I like to create a dropdown box for, but the EFContextProvide Metadata function doesn't automatically import the Enum Entity Type for me to access it, so I created a static dictionay of  that I like to add to the Metadata Mapping, acting as a lookup table. How can I add Enum entity type, so I can call:

```
breeze.EntityManager.createEntity(myEnum,...)
```

right now, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to locate an 'Type' by the name: myEnum
```

Any suggestion?

UPDATE: (I just added the `enumType` info of the `Metadata` function call)

```
"enumType":{"name":"Plugins","isFlags":"false","underlyingType":"Int32","member":["name":"Custom","value":"0"},{"name":"PluginOfTypeA","value":"1"},{"name":"PluginOfTypeB","value":"2"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jay for your response, I was set in the right direction. Here is what I can say about dealing with Enum:

I created a lookup list on the server that I can separately call, to populate the dropdown list. I have a regular array that I initialize on the success promise of the results, list this `data.results[0].myEnumLookup` and then on the Viewmodel, I access that property and set in to the `ko.observableArray()` so I can refer to it in my View. Make sure you set the `value:` property of the `select` tag, to the value of item.

But the problem with doing it this way was that at the Save time, it wasn't reading Enum value and it was treating it as just text, so it was failing, so

More robust solution:

In our application we happen to really benefit from having an Enum and their pre-compile value, since we are using those Enum Domain models in other POCO projects, so I ended creating an EF `DbSet` and proper table that will be populated with all of my Enums values and I can save them into the DB, so now we have the list of items in DB, and I created a single level of inheritance for Enums, so in my controller, I get a `IQueryable` method that will get all of those Enums, and in the breeze application, in my config file, I define the types of enums, and then I will populate lists of items based on different types in my config, so I can refer to it in my view and binding it to the `ko.observableArray()`. Also in my original class, I no longer refer to the Enum, I will create `MyEnumId` as well as `virtual MyEnum` property that will do the mapping automatically in my EF5 setup.

Lesson I learned, even though Enum in .NET4.5 & EF5 is possible to store and read back, but it's not very practical when it comes to SPA front-end technologies, so I prefer having the integer value, and just manage the enums outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question.  By 'Enum entity type' do you mean an 'EntityType' that only has a fixed number of possible instances? If so, you can simply query the entire collection of these entity/instances onto the client and add them directly into your static dictionary. Since, the collection is conceptually immutable, you can query this at the beginning of you session.  Further, you should NEVER need to create an instance of any of these 'entity enums' because you can always extract them from your dictionary.

But maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Let's forget about the Dictionary, that was because I wanted to display more meaningful text. So I have an Enum property in one of my domains, and I see the `enumType`being exported in `Metadata` call. But when editing the item, how can I make a dropdownlist of the possible enums?(I just updated case with with `enumType` info of `Metadata`)

Comment: You'll have to manage that yourself, but you certainly have enough information in the metadata to do so via the entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType(...).getProperty(...) . Take a look at some of the knockout examples that show how to create dropdowns for a fixed set of values.